# Find $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ and their domain. $f(x) = \sqrt {1 − \sin(x)}$ and $g(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm currently stuck on the domain part of composition function for $f\left(g(x)\right)$ and $g\left(f(x)\right)$. I think I have the right answer, but I just want another perspective on the question.

This is a review question for University Calculus.

Comment: Note : $D_{fog} = \{x \in D_g | g(x) \in D_f \}$ , $D_f = \mathbb{R} , D_g = \mathbb{R} - \{-1 \}$

Comment: Please replace *domain* with *maximal domain*. The domain is part of the *definition* of a function, while the *maximal domain* is usually intended as the largest subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that a given expression is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(g(x))=\sqrt{1-\sin\frac{x}{1+x}}$$ and the domain it's $x\neq-1$.

$$g(f(x))=\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}{1+\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}$$ and the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: For g(f(x)) how did you figure out that the domain is R?

Comment: @BoyStruggles Because $1-\sin{x}\geq0$ and  $1+\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}>0$ for all real $x$

Comment: when i tried solving it I got : sin(x) < 0. I moved 1+sqrt1(−sinx) > 0 over and isolated until I got sin(x) < 0

Comment: @BoyStruggles $1>0$ and $\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}\geq0$. Thus, $1+\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$Dom(f)=\mathbb{R}, Im(f)=[0,\sqrt{2}], Dom(g)=\mathbb{R}-\{-1\}, Im(g)=\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$$

$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=\sqrt{1-\sin \left( \dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)}\xrightarrow{Im(g)\subset Dom(f)}Dom(f\circ g)=\mathbb{R}-\{-1\} $$
$$(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{1+\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\xrightarrow{Im(f)\subset Dom(g)}Dom(g\circ f)=\mathbb{R}$$